# Angular2: update a single row when record has been updated in the db

Tags: angular

I have a table that has rows populated via an API call. There is a quantity field(select menu) in this table when I update I call a change event and update the database. I would like to know how to refresh this one row to display the new quantity once the db is updated. My code is as follows:

```
Template:
<div *ngIf="editindex==i">
                     <md-select ngModel name="itemQty" #itemQty="ngModel"  required (change)=" itemQtyUpdate(item.id,itemQty.value)">
                      <md-option *ngFor="let q of itemquantity" [value]="q">
                      {{ q }}
                      </md-option>
                  </md-select>
                </div>

Component:
itemQtyUpdate(id,qt){
         console.log("selected Qty is: ",qt);
         console.log("row ID is: ", id);         
         this.dialogsService.updateQuantity(id,qt)
                            .subscribe(
                                rowQty=>{
                                       return true;
                                },
                                error=>{
                                    console.log("Could not save item, error!");
                                    return Observable.throw(error);
                                }
                    )
         }

Service Module:
updateQuantity(id,orderItem){           
      console.log('***JSON Stringfy update**', JSON.stringify({order_item:orderItem}));
      let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({headers:headers})
      return this._http.put(this.updateQtyUrl + id + "/qty/"+orderItem, JSON.stringify({order_item:orderItem}), {headers:headers})                 
                 .map((res:Response)=>res.json());

  }
```

Thank you for the help.

A

Comment: You want to update `itemquantity` data right. Just find the item in that array and update it with result from database.

Comment: Can you let me know how I can do that?

Comment: Show your `itemquantity` array.